# Protecting In-App Purchases in iOS 7

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, validation, in-app-purchase

On **iOS 6** and below it is desirable to implement receipt validation to make sure that IAPs are not 'hacked' and gotten for FREE without actually paying. My question is, is **iOS 7** still vulnerable to any of these IAP hacks/bypasses (custom DNS, InAppstore hack, etc...)? If so, how can IAPs be protected in **iOS 7**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is iOS 7 still vulnerable to any of these IAP hacks/bypasses (custom
>   DNS, InAppstore hack, etc...)?

No, [as far as I know](http://www.in-appstore.com/). But it's still early to judge.

> how can IAPs be protected in iOS 7?

As long as you verify the receipt on your server, no *generic* hacking method will work on it, unless your app is directly targeted. So if you're doing the server validation you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will keep everything as is for now then.

Answer (score 0):

IOS 7 will have this public vulnerability when devs release the jailbreak. Server validation does stop most of us, but if your app is popular there will be issues.